# python-too many indices for array(remote sensing image)

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I want to imread a  remote sensing image via opencv and then show it.
Because  remote sensing image has four dimension within r,g,b and near-infrared. My idea is to remote the fourth dimension that I can see only rgb image. But when I do that using opencv I got some qustion:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/pycharm_project/tianchi/wenjianduqu_test.py", line 10, in 
<module>
    a=im[:,:,:3]
IndexError: too many indices for array

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code beneath:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np

im=cv2.imread("D:\\Python\\pycharm_project\\tianchi\\cadastral2015.tif",-1)
a=np.zeros((15106,5106,3))
a=im[:,:,:3]

cv2.imshow("1",a)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I don't know where is wrong because it has no problem when the image is a nature image. I need help thank everyone!!

And I tried to show the pixel value of a random point in the 'im' that I got through cv2.imread. It gave me the answer of [0 0 0 255] that reveal I didn't imread the image successfully. I don't know why...

Comment: What does `im.shape` say?

Comment: `a=np.zeros((15106,5106,3))` is pointless if you're just going to replace it with `a=im[:,:,:3]` on the next line.

Comment: That error means that `im` has fewer than 3 dimensions. So trying to access it with `[:, :, :3]` means you are trying to give indices to more dimensions than what `im` contains. Checking `im.shape` to see if it has 3 elements should be the first thing to do here.

Comment: thank you all. I indeed forgot use the `im.shape` to know the shape of the image...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cv2.split` method.

```
channels = cv2.split(im)
a = channels[0]

# or access channels in loop
for channel in channels:
    cv2.imshow("frame", channel)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: sorry, it also doesn't work...when I run it, it only return me the full black image.